# Observable of obsvervable stop sending data after one HttpError

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 Obsvervable :

- A : user input
- B : HttpRequest with one parameter (basic get call using httpclient of Angular)

Actually I have:

```
A.pipe(
      skipWhile(() => bool),
      tap(() => {
        console.log('on change');
      }),
      map((value) => ({
        // some stuff
      })),
      shareReplay()
    );


// I have several api call in fact that's why i don't append whith the first part
        A.pipe(
          tap(() => {
            console.log('On susbscribe');
          }),
          mergeMap(() => B) // My Http Call
        )
        .subscribe(
          (result) => {
            // some stuff
          },
          (error) => {
            if (error.status === 504) {
              messageError = 'Timeout';
            } else {
              messageError = 'The service is temporarily unavailable';
            }
          },
          () => console.log('DONE')
        );
```

My problem is if i change my parameters, the B is trigger with new parameters while i have no error but if i have a timeout (an error for angular) if the user change again the inputs the api is never trigger another time. It's like the if the observable is unsubscribe.

There is the console trace:

```
8.js:9724 on change
8.js:9737 On susbscribe
GET route 504 (Gateway Time-out)
8.js:9724 on change
```

Why and how can I rerun my http call with the new parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

If an observable errors, it will not emit anymore values.  However, you can use [`catchError`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) to return a different observable to prevent this.

In your case, you want the inner observable in your `mergeMap` to catch:

```js
result$ = A$.pipe(
  mergeMap(a => B$.pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      let messageError;
      if (error.status === 504) {
        messageError = 'Timeout';
      } else {
        messageError = 'The service is temporarily unavailable';
      }
      return of(messageError);
    })
  ))
);
```

Here's a simple [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66910050?file=index.ts)